# jupyter --InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'index' in 'field list'")

Tags: mysql, python, pandas, jupyter, sqlalchemy

Tengo un codigo en jupyter que lo que quiero hacer es insertar a la bd, me funciona bien con el ejemplo que tengo comentado, pero al hacerlo con el csv real, me depliega un error.

```
   import pandas as pd 
    df = pd.read_csv('4763.csv',header=[2],delimiter=";")
    df

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
#df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']})
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}"
                       .format(user="root",
                               pw="",
                               db="remu2"))
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='csv',if_exists='append')
```

este es el error

```
InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'index' in 'field list'")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas te crea un indice automaticamente.
df = df.drop(columns='index') te lo elimina o bien index=False al crear el dataframe

Answer (score -2):

```
def insert_csv_file(csv_file_path):
    engine, _ = get_db_session()
    # create table if not exsits
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path, sep='\t', index_col=False, header=0, na_values=['null'])
    pd.io.sql.to_sql(
        df,
        'pax_feature',
        engine,
        schema='slowpay',
        if_exists='append',
        **index=False,**
        index_label='id',
    )
```

use this function can solve this probelm; 
it can save csv to mysql

Comment: Hola @RichardLee . Tu intención es buena pero deberias de leer [como hacer una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ya que tienes vaios errores, empezando por el idioma,  que no ayudan a que el compañero pueda entender tu respuesta. Gracias